# gets not receiving input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, input, output, sentinel

I have a sentinel controlled loop that does not seem to be taking in any input whatsoever:

```
response = " "
until response == "x" do
  puts"
  Xargonia
  =========
  (N)ew
  (L)oad
  (O)ptions
  (Q)uit"
  reponse = gets
  puts response
```

When it tries to output what the user has typed in it only takes what was used to initialize.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'd encourage you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not important to us if you're new, we only care whether you did your research and put in the effort and asked a good question. Please read "[ask]" including the last linked page, and "[mcve]". Your code won't run so it's not meeting the requirements for the second link about "[mcve]".

Comment: Please, include output you get and output you expect. Also you could try to use debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the syntax errors, you are assigning the value of `gets` to `reponse` instead of `response`.  Also, you'll want to remove the newline character from `gets` by chaining `String::chomp`:

```
response = " "
until response == "x" do
  puts "                              # add space between gets and double-quote
  Xargonia
  =========
  (N)ew
  (L)oad
  (O)ptions
  (Q)uit"
  response = gets.chomp               # rename reponse to response; chain .chomp
  puts response
end                                   # add missing end
```